# Angularjs $scope not showing on ng-repeat - works in local but not in live

Tags: angularjs

I have a solution that suddenly stopped showing  data 
It’s a simple but effective  script which does the job without any problems,
My local version in my pc works as expected but in the live version  the same  code it’s not showing
The $scope.links, which I have the data and use ng-repeat to  doesn’t show the code contained in it,
I have even used {{links | json}} to visualize if data is passing through, everything I do works in my local version but in the live version, it doesn’t(it doesn't show error either, just show empty HTML  spaces),  checking in the network to verify if data is flowing, it does !. 
Only the $scope for some reason it’s not showing.
I have tried many things like even upgrade the angular version  but the same problems persist,

Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["angucomplete"]).
    controller("navbarController", function($scope, $http) {


$scope.breadcrumbs = [];
$scope.links = [];

$http.get('/api/source').success(function(data) {

    $scope.nav = data;
    $scope.links = data.sub;


});
```

});

```
<body data-ng-app="app">

<section>
    <div data-ng-controller="navbarController">

        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="item in links" class="{{item.link.className}} {{item.link.imageUrl === '' ? 'no-image' : ''}}">
                <a href="{{item.link.url}}" ng-click="clickNavigation(item); $event.preventDefault();">
                    <span>{{item.link.name}}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>


    </div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does your app starts fine? Any errors in console?

Comment: there is no problem, and that's a bit weird

Comment: Usually this is not a magic. I have a guess you could try.  Do you use minification on prod? If so, tty to change  controller("navbarController", function($scope, $http) to  controller("navbarController", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http)]

Comment: @Franz clean your cache, your templates and http requests are cached (unless specified)

Comment: I have cleaned my cache too, no errors in console, in the network console, data is flowing, as usual, the error is that $scope for some reason doesn't show, as I said before, in local no problems at all, I have tried  different suggestions, with unfortunate not effect on live-server whatsoever, but in local works, and that's a bit frustrating

Comment: What does your /api/source returns on prod? Maybe it is data.data.links?

Comment: Have you inspected your data to see if the data structure is as expected? Put your data into the $scope and display it {{data | json}} to check your data structure.

Comment: yeah I have not problems in local env but  only in live, seems weird anyway, but thanks for your kind feedback.